# How can I fill in missing rows in DataTable efficiently

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable with rows for each minute in a period.

Some minutes are missing though and I want to insert the missing rows by copying data from the row before.

Original table:

[image]

Desired table:

[image]

Below is my attempt, which works, but is very slow.

Is there a faster(execution time) way to do this?

```
   public static DataTable FillGaps(DataTable table)
    {
        var firstDT = table.AsEnumerable().First().Field<DateTime>("utcDT");
        var lastDT = table.AsEnumerable().Last().Field<DateTime>("utcDT");
        var currentDT = firstDT;

        var newTable = table.Clone();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        var rowDT = row.Field<DateTime>("utcDT");
        do
        {
            DataRow newRow;

            if (rowDT == currentDT)
            {
                newRow = newTable.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = (object[])(row.ItemArray);
            }
            else
            {
                newRow = newTable.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = (object[])(newTable.AsEnumerable().Last().ItemArray);
                newRow.SetField("utcDT", currentDT);
            }

            newTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

            currentDT = currentDT.AddMinutes(1);

        } while (currentDT <= rowDT );
    }

    return newTable;
}
```

Comment: You should probably be more specific about what you mean by "Faster" (faster execution? faster to implement?). Also maybe a simplified before and after snapshot of your table? Just something made in 5 minutes in paint, can make your problem a lot easier to understand :-)

Comment: @Noceo See edits please

Comment: Have you tried making a new empty table, with the desired number of rows (should be easy to calculate, if its one for each hour) and then either copy data from your existing table (if it exists) or interpolate the data if it does not?

Answer (score 0):

For loops are slower than linq methods.  Not sure if code below is faster but uses linq :

```
   class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            DataTable utcDT = new DataTable("utcDT");
            utcDT.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            utcDT.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(decimal));

            utcDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("1/28/2016 00:02:00"), 123.97 });
            utcDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("1/28/2016 00:03:00"), 123.76 });
            utcDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("1/28/2016 00:04:00"), 123.74 });
            utcDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("1/28/2016 00:06:00"), 123.81 });
            utcDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("1/28/2016 00:07:00"), 123.74 });
            utcDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("1/28/2016 00:08:00"), 123.81 });
            utcDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("1/28/2016 00:12:00"), 123.5 });

            DateTime minTime = utcDT.AsEnumerable().Min(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date"));
            DateTime maxTime = utcDT.AsEnumerable().Max(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date"));

            int totalMinutes = maxTime.Subtract(minTime).Minutes;

            List<DateTime> newDates = Enumerable.Range(0, totalMinutes + 1).Select(x => minTime.AddMinutes(x)).ToList();

            DataTable cloneTable = utcDT.Clone();

            var join = from nDate in newDates 
                       join  row in utcDT.AsEnumerable() on nDate equals row.Field<DateTime>("Date") into emptyRow
                       from row in emptyRow.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                       select new { row = row, date = nDate };

            decimal lastValue = 0.0M;

            foreach (var joinRow in join)
            {
                if (joinRow.row == null)
                {
                    cloneTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { joinRow.date, lastValue });
                }
                else
                {
                    cloneTable.Rows.Add(joinRow.row.ItemArray);
                    lastValue = joinRow.row.Field<decimal>("Value");
                }
            }



        }
    }
```